# What kind of verb phrase is it when “is” in the present tense is immediately followed by another verb that’s itself in the past tense?

Tags: terminology, past-tense, present-tense, clauses, be

Please con­sider this ex­am­ple of three sen­tences in se­quence:

1. The build­ing is **de­stroyed**.
2. The rub­ble is then **re­moved**.
3. The rub­ble is **bro­ken** into smaller pieces.

What kind of verb phrase is it when I fol­low *is* with yet an­other
in­flected verb, and why do we call it that?

I think it’s still present tense but I can't fig­ure out how *is*
can be used with a past-tense verb.  I know that *is* is the verb,
and thus it is present tense, but what would *de­stroyed* be? An
ad­jec­tive?

Also, based on the first two sen­tences’ pat­tern,
shouldn’t the third sen­tence use *broke* not *bro­ken* so that
it is **also** in the past tense just like *de­stroyed* and *re­moved*
had been?

3. The rub­ble is **broke** into smaller pieces.

Comment: These three sentences, in context with one another, are examples of the Passive construction, which uses a form of _be_ followed by the past participle (not the past form) of the verb. _Someone destroys the building. Then someone removes the rubble. Someone ships the rubble to a landfill._ All these sentences are active, but they can be transformed into the passive sentences above.

Answer (score 0):

John Lawler in a comment wrote:

> These three sentences, in context with one another, are examples of the Passive construction, which uses a form of *be* followed by the past participle (not the past form) of the verb. *Someone destroys the building. Then someone removes the rubble. Someone ships the rubble to a landfill.* All these sentences are active, but they can be transformed into the passive sentences above.